# Label missing on axes in pspicture

Tags: labels, pst-plot

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=0.1cm}
\savedata{\data}[{1,64},{2,32},{3,16},{4,8},{5,4},{6,2},{7,1}]
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-4)(8.6,79)
  \psaxes[
    dy=10,
    labels=none,
    ticklinestyle=dotted,
    tickwidth=0.5pt,
    xticksize=0 70,
    yticksize=0 7
  ]{->}(0,0)(-0.2,-2)(7.5,75)[Format,0][Ark A6-papir,90]
  \psaxes[
    dy=10,
    Dy=10,
    mathLabel=false,
    xLabels={,A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6}
  ]{->}(0,0)(-0.2,-2)(7.5,75)
  \dataplot[
    plotstyle=dots,
    dotstyle=o,
    fillcolor=red
  ]{\data}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The `A6` label on the x-axis is missing; how do I get PSTricks to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
  \psaxes[
    dy=10,Dy=10,
    mathLabel=false,
    xLabels={,A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6}]{->}(7.5,75)
```

Comment: Then there is a `0` at the bottom of ther verticcal axis. How do I remove this?

Comment: I just found the option `showorigin=false` but is there a 'better' way, i.e., is this command outdated or something similar?